# Inheritance vs Injection in use of Angular 4 service

Tags: angular, typescript

I am a bit new to world of Angular. I am currently using Angular-4.4.6.
**My scenario is as follows:**
I have 3 components (for e.g. C1, C2, C3) each of which use their own services(e.g. S1, S2, S3 resp.) which then call "http.get()" to get the data from rest backend.
What I want to know is instead of injecting the "http:HttpClient" in each of the three services, should I just create a 'RestService' class which has all the rest calls like get(), post(), put(), delete() and then:

- extend this base class into each of my 3 services where I will
  subscribe to these method calls of base class and then use the data
  fetched?

OR

- inject the 'RestService' which has generic methods into constructor of each of my services and then use these services by subscribing them?

Are there any performance hits with these two approaches?

Comment: Why would you wan't to do that? `HttpClient` is already your `RestService` so you should just inject it in each of your services.

Comment: I usually use only one "RestService", directly from components. It makes more sense, as the components themselves can handle the error or success handling. 

that way you keep your S1, S2 etc. services, but any backend communication is used in a different service.

If you inherit the methods which return observable / promises, you would just pass them trough anyway from the in-between services. 

To answer your question: I think the latter is better, you use single communication endpoints and parameter those differently - but I don't know any performance differences.

Answer (score 1):

I like to have a "base service"

```
export class ServiceModel<T>{
    type: string;
    url: string;
    ...
    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    }
    list(): Observable<T[]> {
        return this._http.get<T[]>(this.url)
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in data1Service

```
export interface IData1
{
    id:number;
    desc:string;
    ...
}

@Injectable()
export class Data1Service extends ServiceModel<IData1> {
    type:string="data1";
    url:string="myurl/data1";

    constructor(http: HttpClient) {
        super(http)
    }
}
```

But I don't kwon if this answer resolve your question :(